# Authentication Popup using Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks, win32com, pywinauto

I'm able to send keys to handle the authentication popup of a site using Selenium and win32com.client. It is working fine when I run the code manually (running a Jupyter Notebook).

The error occurs when I convert .ipynb to .py and schedule it to run automatically using Windows Task Scheduler. It get stuck into the authentication popup window.

I have tried the options below:

1.) This works fine in notebook

```
shell = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
shell.SendKeys("username", + "{TAB}" + "password" + "{TAB}" + "{ENTER}")
```

2.) Just trying some alternatives and its working in notebook

```
shell = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

try:
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    shell.SendKeys("username", + "{TAB}" + "password" + "{TAB}" + "{ENTER}")

except NoAlertPresentException:
    shell.SendKeys("username", + "{TAB}" + "password" + "{TAB}" + "{ENTER}")
```

Is there a better approach on how to run this code (.py) automatically using Task Scheduler?

Comment: Updates: The code works in .py only when there is an active desktop session. Whenever the computer detects inactivity before the scheduled run, the task wont push through. Is there a way I can unlock the system and lock it back after the process. BTW, I have added pywinauto to minimize the Console Windows and SetFocus to Chrome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Works well with .ipynb and py while in active desktop session
updates: 
added codes to minimize the Console Window Class

```
app = Application().Connect(title ='path' + 'python.exe', class_name = 'ConsoleWindowClass')
cwc = app.ConsoleWindowClass
cwc.Minimize()

app = Application().Connect(title ='page', class_name = 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1')
widget = app.Chrome_WidgetWin_1
widget.Minimize()
time.sleep(2) # will allow the some time before executing other task
widget.Maximize()
widget.SetFocus()
time.sleep(3)
shell.SendKeys("username", + "{TAB}" + "password" + "{TAB}" + "{ENTER}")
```

It won't work when the computer is locked. Work around is to send a pyautogui for mouse events.

Again, it might not be the best solution but this is my temporary solution until your best approach :)